# Life is fleeting, “vitae est labilis”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Can someone please tell me the appropriate translation for “life is fleeting”. So far I have come up with “*vitae est labilis*”.

Answer (score 6):

This, I guess, is drawing on Horace's Ode to Postumus:
"Sadly, the fleeting years slip away."

> Eheu fugaces Postume, Postume, Labuntur anni,

*vitae labilis*  (without *est* ) means 'slippery lives,' or 'stumbling lives.'
For 'Fleeting years' Horace chose *Fugaces Anni.*

'Life is Fleeting,' if you would like to follow Horace, would be ***Vita Fugax,*** or *Fugax est Vita.*

***Fugax*** [Fugax II. Trop. A. www.perseus.tufts](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DF%3Aentry%20group%3D30%3Aentry%3Dfugax) is the reference.

Comment: *Fugiō* is a good verb for this, cf *tempus fugit*

Comment: @Draconis Can you write a separate answer around that idea? It's worth more than a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, would it be better to simply have vita fugax or something like vita est fugaces or vita fugaces?

Comment: @Hugh *Vitae **sunt** fugaces*? The singular form is a far better choice, though.

Comment: Not 'vita est fugaces' because -st f- is awkward to pronounce; and it would have to be 'vitae **sunt** fugaces' "lives are fleeting". Not 'vita fugaces' because it means 'Avoid the runners.' Vita Fugax or Tom Cotton's Vita Brevis are really your best choices.

Answer (score 4):

*Ars longa, vita brevis* is an ancient translation from the Greek of Hippocrates, occurring in the first lines of his *Aphorismi*.

The aphorism is well-known and understood in English. The best answer in my view is undoubtedly **vita brevis**.